# Displaying Contact Number and Contact Name in a custom list view

Tags: android, listview, simplecursoradapter

Can anyone tell me how should i display the phone number and the contact name in a custom list view?
The code is pasted below

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;

public class AddContacts extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    ListView list;
    Cursor cursor;
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;
    String phoneNumber;
    Button AddNumber;
    EditText number1;
    EditText number2;
    EditText number3;
    String contact1;
    String contact2;
    CheckBox checkBox;
    String contact_name;

    static final String TAG = "In AddContacts";

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listview);
        AddNumber = (Button) findViewById(R.id.AddNumbers);
        number1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.NumberField1);
        number2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.NumberField2);
        number3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.NumberField3);
        AddNumber.setOnClickListener(this);
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lists);


        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");



        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null,
                null, null);

        String[] nameNumberArray = new String[cursor.getCount()];
        Log.d("rows", Integer.toString(cursor.getCount()));

        Log.d("phone", "here");
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            String phoneNumber =

            cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
            String name = cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
            Log.i("Number + Name", phoneNumber + name);
        }
        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {

            int i = 0;
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    phoneNumber = cursor
                            .getString(cursor
                                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

                    contact_name = cursor
                            .getString(cursor
                                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                    nameNumberArray[i] = contact_name + "  , " + phoneNumber;
                    i++;
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }

        }

        final String[] FROM = { nameNumberArray[0], nameNumberArray[1] };
        final int[] TO = { R.id.contact_name, R.id.phone_number, };
        adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row, cursor, FROM, TO);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        cursor.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {


        Log.d(TAG, "onClicked method");


    }
}
```

The ROW.xml file is a custom listView with a checkbox and two textView to it.
The code pulls the data from the contacts and displays it in the LogCat. I cant figure out how to display the name and the number in my custom view using simpleCursorAdapter.

The row.xml file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/contact_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="John Doe"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/phone_number"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/contact_name"
        android:text="(999)999-9999"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Can anyone guide me?
Thanks.

Comment: do you want to use a custom adapter? i have a solution that displays name and phone number using custom adapter

Comment: I can give that a try. Do i need to get rid of simpleCursorAdapter for that?

Comment: wll if you want i can provide an altenative solution

Comment: Do you have anything which could help me with SimpleCursor? If not i can give the custom adapter a try.

Comment: no i don't use a simplecursor adapter. but i use a custom adapter.

Comment: thats fine..can you please post the custom adapter code for reference?

Comment: sure give me a moment

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since op asked for the solution using custom adapter i have posted the below.(from the comments)

Display.java

```
public class Display extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener{

    List<String> name1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> phno1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    MyAdapter ma ;
    Button select;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.display);

        getAllContacts(this.getContentResolver());
        ListView lv= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
            ma = new MyAdapter();
            lv.setAdapter(ma);
            lv.setOnItemClickListener(this); 
            lv.setItemsCanFocus(false);
            lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
            // adding
           select = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        select.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                  StringBuilder checkedcontacts= new StringBuilder();
                System.out.println(".............."+ma.mCheckStates.size());
                for(int i = 0; i < name1.size(); i++)

                    {
                    if(ma.mCheckStates.get(i)==true)
                    {
                         checkedcontacts.append(name1.get(i).toString());
                         checkedcontacts.append("\n");

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println("Not Checked......"+name1.get(i).toString());
                    }


                }

                Toast.makeText(Display.this, checkedcontacts,1000).show();
            }       
        });


    }
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         ma.toggle(arg2);
    }

    public  void getAllContacts(ContentResolver cr) {

        Cursor phones = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,null,null, null);
        while (phones.moveToNext())
        {
          String name=phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
          String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
          System.out.println(".................."+phoneNumber); 
          name1.add(name);
          phno1.add(phoneNumber);
        }

        phones.close();
     }
    class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener
    {  private SparseBooleanArray mCheckStates;
       LayoutInflater mInflater;
        TextView tv1,tv;
        CheckBox cb;
        MyAdapter()
        {
            mCheckStates = new SparseBooleanArray(name1.size());
            mInflater = (LayoutInflater)Display.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return name1.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            View vi=convertView;
            if(convertView==null)
             vi = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null); 
             TextView tv= (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
             tv1= (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
             cb = (CheckBox) vi.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
             tv.setText("Name :"+ name1.get(position));
             tv1.setText("Phone No :"+ phno1.get(position));
             cb.setTag(position);
             cb.setChecked(mCheckStates.get(position, false));
             cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

            return vi;
        }
         public boolean isChecked(int position) {
                return mCheckStates.get(position, false);
            }

            public void setChecked(int position, boolean isChecked) {
                mCheckStates.put(position, isChecked);
                System.out.println("hello...........");
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            public void toggle(int position) {
                setChecked(position, !isChecked(position));
            }
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                boolean isChecked) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

             mCheckStates.put((Integer) buttonView.getTag(), isChecked);         
        }   
    }   
}
```

display.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

   <ListView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_above="@+id/button1"

       android:id="@+id/lv"/>

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/button1"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         android:text="Select" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Explanation:

The above uses a Custom Adapter. A custom layout `row.xml` with 2 textviews and one checkbox is inflated for each row. `getAllContacts()` will get all contacts from the contacts list and you store them in a list.

Custom Adapter displays the items in a custom layout inflated for each row.

When you check the check box and click display displays a toast with selected contacts name.

Snap shot

[image]

Comment: @user2511882 i updated my post let me know if you need further assistance

Comment: mInflater = (LayoutInflater)AddDatabase.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
What is the AddDatabase here for?

Comment: change it to `Display.this`. a copy paste error. that's `Activity context`. Your `ActivityName.this` is the Acctivity context.

Comment: This things works like magic. I approved it. I would love to upvote it as well but i dont have enough reps for that. But thanks a ton!!! I have spend close to 3 hours on this.. CHEERS!!!

Comment: @Raghunandan thanks for posting..it worked as a miracle

Comment: @Raghunandan if there were let's say 2 contact numbers of contact name recharge how would you display them in a single row of listview along with first phone no?

Comment: @Darkie ask a different question. Why do you ask a question in comment section.

Comment: @Raghunandan because I tried this code and it's working but showing the 2 contact numbers of same person in separate row with the same name ... ?

Comment: This code will display all the contacts. Duplicate records, because of facebook, gmail etc contact's number. Do you know how to display only unique contacts ? There are more items with same number and name. Please help me to resolve this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: This code shows some of my contacts with repetitive values :(

Comment: @kgandroid no it does not. Secondly you should be using a CursorAdapter. This method is not efficient

Comment: Cant understand what mistake I ma doing :( :(

Comment: The name and numbers are printed in my log but not in the sorted order.But when I bind them in list all goes wrong.It shows only 3-4 repetative contacts

Comment: @kgandroid your adapter code is where the problem is. Fix it.

Comment: Can you please tell me the mistake i am doing??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60598/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-kgandroid).

Comment: works perfectly.to sort the phonebook entries,just change the cursor to:    Cursor phones = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,null,null, Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");

Comment: Would there be an easy way to get the thumbnail photo from the contact as well? By using this code you wrote.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should call `cursor.moveToFirst()` again before passing it to the `SimpleCursorAdapter`, as right now you're sending a "finished" cursor.

Besides that, your code seems fine. You can compare it to the code [here](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-cursoradapter-sqlite.html), which does something similar (But with a user-defined database).

Comment: can you please point out which line should i make the change to?