# How I get the selected contact list and display it in a list view?

Tags: android, android-contacts

I've created a custom contact picker that allows for multiple contact selection. And how I get the selected contact list and display it in a list view back to the app like this below.?

[image]

If you want to see my contact picker code, let me knw.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17256932/displaying-contact-number-and-contact-name-in-a-custom-list-view/17258014#17258014. check this listview with contacts and checkbox. might help

Comment: Yea, I've seen that. But I don't want to make a toast. I wanna to display back to the app after you have clicked on the select button. Thanks.

Comment: you need to modify the same according to your requirement. What you do you mean by display back to the app. its already displayed in the listview.

Comment: Ok. I meant to display it like the above image after the user clicked select button.

Comment: you need to pass the value selected to the next activity and display as in next activity.

Comment: OK. I get it. Thank you so much!