# Custom Contacts List in Android

Tags: android, android-contacts

I am looking to build a local Contacts list in Android. The user selects, say 3 contacts, from the address book and the code needs to save this list locally. The list should include Contact name, mobile number and email address. The user should also be able to edit this list. I am new to Android and struggling to get a solution for this.

The app I am building needs a user to create a local contacts list. I need to be able to extract the full contacts list from the Address Book and then the user gets to choose a limited number of contacts which get saved for later retrieval/modifications.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17256932/displaying-contact-number-and-contact-name-in-a-custom-list-view/17258014#17258014. check this if it helps. add row.xml with 2 textviews and 1 checkbox not shown in the code posted

Comment: This is a sample of custom contact list implementation : https://github.com/alirezaeiii/Rebtel-Contacts-Clone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try Retrieving a List of Contacts in Android Developer.

This [link](http://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/retrieve-names.html) may helps you to retrive the contact list.

Answer (score 0):

Replace book objects with contact objects in the following tutorial and it might be useful...

http://stirfriedcode.blogspot.jp/2013/11/getting-specific-data-from-sqlite.html

Answer (score -1):

I tried a new workaround and adapter-free solution . It's worth to have a look at :

https://github.com/draxdave/ConstraintAccordion

[image]