# How to get selected items in listview with checkbox on button click

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, contacts, android-contacts

I am trying to get contacts on a listview and get selected items on button click. I use custom adapter, but I don't know how to get the selected items.

I tries lots of different methods like setOnItemChangeListener to store change state items. But none working.

Here is the code,

```
package com.example.callblocker;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.Checkable;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * Developed by Azharahmed
 */
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    private ArrayList<Contact> contact_list = null;
    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog = null;
    private contactAdapter mContactAdapter = null;
    private Runnable mViewcontacts = null;

    private ArrayList<Contact> items;
    boolean[] isChecked;
    Cursor mCursor;
    ListView lv;
    Button blockSelectedBtn;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        contact_list = new ArrayList<Contact>();
        lv = getListView();

        blockSelectedBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        blockSelectedBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                for (int i = 0; i < mContactAdapter.getCount(); i++)
                {
                    Contact contact = mContactAdapter.getItem(i);
                    if (((Checkable) contact).isChecked())
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                                contact.getContactName() + " is Checked!!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        mViewcontacts = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                getContacts();
            }
        };

        Thread thread = new Thread(null, mViewcontacts, "ContactReadBackground");
        thread.start();
        mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this,
                "Please Wait...", "Retriving Contacts...", true);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private void getContacts() {

        try {

            String[] projection = new String[] {
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER,
                    ContactsContract.Contacts._ID };

            mCursor = managedQuery(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                    projection, ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER
                            + "=?", new String[] { "1" },
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);

            while (mCursor.moveToNext()) {
                Contact contact = new Contact();

                String contactId = mCursor.getString(mCursor
                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                contact.setContactName(mCursor.getString(mCursor
                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME)));
                contact_list.add(contact);
            }
            isChecked = new boolean[mCursor.getCount()];

            for (int i = 0; i < isChecked.length; i++) {
                isChecked[i] = false;
            }

            this.mContactAdapter = new contactAdapter(this, R.layout.listview,
                    contact_list);
            lv.setAdapter(this.mContactAdapter);
            mCursor.close();

            runOnUiThread(returnRes);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("getContacts", e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public class contactAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Contact> {

        public contactAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                ArrayList<Contact> items1) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, items1);
            items = items1;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder mViewHolder;

            mViewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.listview, parent, false);
            mViewHolder.cb = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
            mViewHolder.cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "item changed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            });
            convertView.setTag(mViewHolder);

            if (isChecked[position] == true)
                mViewHolder.cb.setChecked(true);
            else
                mViewHolder.cb.setChecked(false);
            mViewHolder.cb
                    .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                                boolean ischecked) {
                            if (buttonView.isChecked()) {
                                isChecked[position] = true;
                            } else {
                                isChecked[position] = false;
                            }
                        }
                    });

            Contact contacts = items.get(position);
            if (contacts != null) {
                if (mViewHolder.cb != null) {
                    mViewHolder.cb.setText(contacts.getContactName());
                }
            }

            return convertView;
        }
    }

    public class ViewHolder {
        CheckBox cb;
    }

    private Runnable returnRes = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (mProgressDialog.isShowing())
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            mContactAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };

   }
```

Here is one of the error code.

```
    12-13 16:36:02.407: E/AndroidRuntime(14885): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-13 16:36:02.407: E/AndroidRuntime(14885): java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.callblocker.Contact
12-13 16:36:02.407: E/AndroidRuntime(14885):    at com.example.callblocker.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:62)
12-13 16:36:02.407: E/AndroidRuntime(14885):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2552)
12-13 16:36:02.407: E/AndroidRuntime(14885):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9229)
12-13 16:36:02.407: E/AndroidRuntime(14885):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
12-13 16:36:02.407: E/AndroidRuntime(14885):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-13 16:36:02.407: E/AndroidRuntime(14885):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
12-13 16:36:02.407: E/AndroidRuntime(14885):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3701)
12-13 16:36:02.407: E/AndroidRuntime(14885):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-13 16:36:02.407: E/AndroidRuntime(14885):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-13 16:36:02.407: E/AndroidRuntime(14885):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
12-13 16:36:02.407: E/AndroidRuntime(14885):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:624)
12-13 16:36:02.407: E/AndroidRuntime(14885):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Any hint or suggestion will be very helpful.

Comment: check this if it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18162931/android-get-selected-item-using-checkbox-in-listview-when-i-click-a-button

Comment: Thanks, but the problem I'm facing is my app can't get selected item. Problem lies in blockSelectedBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    for (int i = 0; i < mContactAdapter.getCount(); i++)
                {
                    Contact contact = mContactAdapter.getItem(i);
                    if (mViewHolder.cb.isChecked())
                    {Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,contact.getContactName() + " is Checked!!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}}});

Comment: What is line 62 MainActivity.java and check this if it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17256932/displaying-contact-number-and-contact-name-in-a-custom-list-view/17258014#17258014

Comment: line 62 is Contact contact = mContactAdapter.getItem(i);

Comment: `mContactAdapter.getItem(i)` returns null.

Comment: @Raghunandan Do you know any solution?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43141/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-isuru)

Comment: Join the chat @ http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43141/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-isuru

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using [SparseBooleanArray](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseBooleanArray.html) to get the selected items (from positions).
Similar stackoverflow questions with relevant answers:

1. [How to get Selected items from Multi Select List View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4590856/how-to-get-selected-items-from-multi-select-list-view)
2. [How to get all checked items from a ListView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4831918/how-to-get-all-checked-items-from-a-listview)

Answer (score 1):

I dont know much droid programming but typically to log this info from user you would want to setup an action listener and then for each action log and save the data.
To write an Action Listener, follow the steps given below:

Declare an event handler class and specify that the class either implements an ActionListener interface or extends a class that implements an ActionListener interface. For example:
public class MyClass implements ActionListener { 
Register an instance of the event handler class as a listener on one or more components. For example:
someComponent.addActionListener(instanceOfMyClass);
Include code that implements the methods in listener interface. For example:
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
    ...//code that reacts to the action... 
}

here is a how to on doing that-
[tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)