# Android : checkbox automatically unchecked after scrolldown to listview

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, unchecked

Here is my contact picker list activity which contain list of contacts. i want to pick multiple contacts via checkbox and send data to them. 
The Problem is : when i checked one contact and scroll down list view and i am back to scroll up the checked box automatically unchecked

here my contact picker activity :

```
if (cb.isChecked()) {
                        Log.i("in if check box", receiver_id+"++++");

                        obj_Send_data = new send_data();
                        obj_Send_data.setReceiver_id(receiver_id);
                        obj_Send_data.setGcm_reg_id(gcm_reg_id);
                        id_arrArrayList.add(obj_Send_data);
                        Log.i("arraylist in if lisze", "++"+ id_arrArrayList.size());

                        Log.i("array list obj","++"+obj_Send_data);

                    } else if (!cb.isChecked()) {

                        id_arrArrayList.remove(obj_Send_data);
                        Log.i("arraylist in else lisze", "++"+ id_arrArrayList.size());

                    }


================================================================================================
here my custom listview adapter
================================================================================================


public class CustomListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context cm1;
    ArrayList<PhoneContactInfo> itemdetails,arraylist;
    LayoutInflater l_inflater;
    String[] str;
    ArrayList<String> image1;
    int[] intarray_;
    boolean[] itemChecked;
      /* List<Registure_user> registure_user_list;*/


 private static class ViewHolder {
     public ImageView imageView;
     public TextView name,number;
     CheckBox ch;

 }
    public CustomListViewAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<PhoneContactInfo> list,List<Registure_user> registure_user,ArrayList<String> image) {
        cm1=context;
        itemdetails=list;
        l_inflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
        image1=image;
//      registure_user_list=registure_user;
        arraylist=new ArrayList<PhoneContactInfo>();
        arraylist.addAll(list);
        itemChecked = new boolean[arraylist.size()];
    }


    public int getCount() {
        return itemdetails.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        return itemdetails.get(arg0);
    }

    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        return arg0;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final ViewHolder holder;
        View vi = convertView;

        if(vi==null)
            vi = l_inflater.inflate(R.layout.custcontactview, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.number = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.txtContactNumber);
            holder.name= (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.txtContactName);
            holder.imageView = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.imageView1_icon);
            holder.ch=(CheckBox) vi.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1_check);
            holder.ch.setClickable(false);


            holder.name.setText(itemdetails.get(position).getcontactName());
            holder.number.setText(itemdetails.get(position).getcontactNumber());

            if(!image1.get(position).equals("0")){
                holder.imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.ch.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                vi.setTag(image1.get(position)+" ");


                holder.ch.setTag(vi.getTag());
                Log.i("tag", vi.getTag()+"==");
            } 
            else {
                holder.imageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                holder.ch.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                vi.setTag("0");
            }

            return vi;
    }
    public void filter(String charText) {
        charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
        itemdetails.clear();
        if (charText.length() == 0) {
            itemdetails.addAll(arraylist);
        } else {
            for (int i=0;i<arraylist.size();i++ ) {
                if (arraylist.get(i).getcontactName().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())
                        .contains(charText)) {
                    Log.i("serch", arraylist.get(i).getcontactName());
                    itemdetails.addAll(arraylist);
                }
            }
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: coz listview recycles views. check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17256932/displaying-contact-number-and-contact-name-in-a-custom-list-view

Comment: This is cause listView recycles the views so you can use **SparseBooleanArray** for check- unchecked your checkbox and pass the length of your arraylist to **SparseBooleanArray** in your Custom Adapter Constructor.

Comment: @PiYusH GuPtA have you any example ??

Comment: Why are you making your Checkbox unclickable? and there is a wrong in your `ViewHolder` pattern...

Comment: maitain it somewhere in order to maintain the states when you scroll !

Comment: @SandyAngel Yeah. check this http://dharmendra4android.blogspot.in/2012/10/multi-selection-listview-example-in.html

Comment: You just have use SparseBooleanArray in BaseAdapter class

Answer (score 0):

Its `getview()` method behavior which create new view every time whenever user scroll the view. Check my post at my blog simple replace `toggle button with checkbok` and execute it.

[Getview Method Wierd in Listview](http://robinhood87.blogspot.in/2013/03/getview-method-wierd-in-listview-its.html)